# Is it possible to infer the value of a Record type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want typescript to infer the type of `statusColor` as `yellow` instead of `Color`. Is this possible in typescript?

```
type Status = 'Invalid' | 'Progress' | 'Complete' | 'Error';

type Color=  'yellow' | 'red' | 'green' | 'blue';

const STATUS_TO_COLOR: Record<
  Status,
  Color
> = {
  Invalid: 'yellow',
  Progress: 'blue',
  Complete: 'green',
  Error: 'red',
} as const;

const statusColor = STATUS_TO_COLOR["Invalid"];
     //   ^ inferred as Color, can it be infered as "yellow"?
```

[Playground link to the code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCuBnKBeKByAkgOwDd4AbASwBMsoAfbABQCcB7AcwYhRStqwGEmAtmGIRgEbtgCiDZgywBuALAAoFaEhR+xJg0zYQEYtoDuErO0o1sbCBDxmARsSTilq5QGMmeFMFgAVAEF-AFUYAH1-AHlw3iiAGSiAJQAuKCSILwZyAB4VKFgEZBQAGnzNJm0GFQA+DCgAb3L8IjJyNKwDIyZTMuUCxlZ2Tg6nFyw+gv4hETEOmzsJ8ulZDosl5QBfKHg0Lx9gNxV93wDgsMiYuMSkgCZ6pv6oFpIKDq6TDYHmGxHsMfEkwqM1EEHm7EWQJWOjWEEofW2uygJ0OKmO3lOvkQqC0OnqMCCoQi0ViCWSAG0AEQvNqUgC68ig6IOUCxxVxDHumAJ52JVzJdypNIo9MZaOUAHoJcj4HgoOoOB4GKQwH5SHgAGYQBjygAW0HgHmQJCgrRcUCYGtZRRxlTxZAA1tBSH4PLKoOQmFANXi2baqrcAPzioA)

I have tried using different approach but none seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second way you've tryed is the only way

You may test it for being `<Status, Color>` tho

```
const STATUS_TO_COLOR = {
  Invalid: 'yellow',
  Progress: 'blue',
  Complete: 'green',
  Error: 'red',
} satisfies Record<Status, Color>;
```

(ts4.9+)